# Making a discord bot move a member to the afk channel once they deafen

Tags: discord.py

ok so basically I want to make a bot to move a user to afk as soon as they deafen, I know very little about coding and wanted some help.

all I really want is for it to do is to scan all voice channels and move any deafened user it sees to the afk channel

here is the code i have:

```
     channel = self.bot.get_channel(800674042247118878)
     if after.deaf and after.channel:
        await member.move_to(.afkChannelId);
```

again I have absolutely no clue how to code and am basically just using what I could find

ty for the help <3

Comment: Why did you tag the question as "discord.js"? You're clearly using python with discord.py.

Answer (score 2):

You should check [VOICE_STATE_UPDATE](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update). This event is raised when a user's voice state changes. This includes when a user joins, leaves, or moves between voice channels, as well as their mute and deaf status for themselves and on the server.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member.VoiceState.self_deaf:
         await member.move_to(afkchannel)
```

Comment: thank you for the help, it means a lot to me. 

btw I'm now having an issue when I try to start up the bot. here is what I get:


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m

Comment: didn't notice until now.

@bot.event
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)←[39m